# Why does \babelensure change the alignment of section headings and how can I prevent it?

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, babel, languages, welsh

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[welsh,british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\newcommand{\cymraeg}[1]{{\selectlanguage{welsh}#1}}
\newcommand{\welsh}[1]{\foreignlanguage{welsh}{#1}}
\babelensure[include=\bibname,include=\contentsname,include=\glossaryname,include=\indexname]{welsh}
\newcommand*{\colophonname}{\cymraeg{Coloffon} --- Colophon}
\newenvironment{colophon}{%
  \section*{\colophonname}%
  \markboth{Coloffon}{Colophon}%
  \small
  \quote
}{\endquote}
\begin{document}
\begin{colophon}
  As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown
\end{colophon}
\renewcommand*{\colophonname}{\welsh{Coloffon} --- Colophon}
\begin{colophon}
  As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown
\end{colophon}
\end{document}
```

I would expect this code to produce two identical colophons, each with a left-aligned header. However, the first is clearly offset to the right.

[image: divergent colophons]

If I comment out the line

```
\babelensure[include=\bibname,include=\contentsname,include=\glossaryname,include=\indexname]{welsh}
```

then the result is as I would expect.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not that it's altering alignment *per se*, but rather that there is a stray space (missing `%` at a line end) in the definition of `\bbl@ensure`. For each entry in the ensured list this adds one space before your text, which makes it look roughly centred here. Add the following fixed definition to your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\def\bbl@ensure#1#2#3{%
  \def\bbl@tempb##1{% elt for \bbl@ensured list
    \ifx##1\@empty\else
      \in@{##1}{#2}%
      \ifin@\else
        \toks@\expandafter{##1}%
        \edef\bbl@tempa{%
          \noexpand\DeclareRobustCommand
          \bbl@csarg\noexpand{ensure@\languagename}[1]{%
            \noexpand\foreignlanguage{\languagename}%
            {\ifx\relax#3\else
              \noexpand\fontencoding{#3}\noexpand\selectfont
             \fi
             ########1}}}%
        \bbl@tempa
        \edef##1{%
           \bbl@csarg\noexpand{ensure@\languagename}%
           {\the\toks@}}% The unprotected line end was here!
      \fi
      \expandafter\bbl@tempb
    \fi}%
  \expandafter\bbl@tempb\bbl@ensured\@empty
  \def\bbl@tempa##1{% elt for include list
    \ifx##1\@empty\else
      \bbl@csarg\in@{ensure@\languagename\expandafter}\expandafter{##1}%
      \ifin@\else
        \bbl@tempb##1\@empty
      \fi
      \expandafter\bbl@tempa
    \fi}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Yes, it's a bug. I'll upload a fix in a few days.

Comment: I needed to add a curly bracket. I hope that you do not mind that I edited your code above in case anybody else needs it. It works great with the curly bracket added - thanks! @JavierBezos Excellent - thanks to you also :-).

Comment: I don't mind. Unfortunately I couldn't publish the new version in CTAN due to some problems in the packaged zip file which I cannot solve right now (perhaps in month or so) :-(. Sorry.